# Adding separate column COUNTRY in SE database

Tags: feature-request, location

Well, there are many contracts or recruiters, who search for candidates by location. StackExchange is of course, one of the good source for finding people, and many people might need to find users by country (i.e. querying on datexplorer.se, for users, which are from [XYZ country](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1456065/top-users-from-dubai)).
Maybe, it would be good that there was a separate field for COUNTRY for users in StackExchange profile, thus it might have a positive effect?

---

*( Of course I said, that field should be optional - users can ignore and don't fill that field, but many users, might want to fill that, and why not allow them to do so if they wish to be found easily by location by potential recruiters?)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the query to exclude users whose location contains "US" or "United States". See [modified query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/540195/top-users-georgia).

Answer (score 6):

First, the location field is a free form field, so there is no validation whatsoever and users can fill in anything in there (see for example the location field in the user profile of [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)). There is no reliable way to find users in a specific region. It all depends if users have filled in the field the same way and unambiguous, which they don't.

Adding a country field doesn't add anything useful to the purpose of the site (just as the location in my opinion). And even if they did add it, I don't think it will be of much use if users don't fill it in the same way.

Comment: Shog9 must have updated his profile since you posted this answer, as it now says "Frontier, WA, USA".